# Finding repeat numbers in a file (C++)

Tags: c++

I have looked around for awhile but I'm still stuck on a bit of logic.

I have a file with a list of birthdays. I want to find the most common birthday (month/day).

My logic so far:

```
    int maxValue = 0;

    int maxBday;

    while (Bday >> month >> b >> day >> b >> year) // take in values a line at a time from the file

    {
        int a = totalDays(month, day); //function finds number of days into the year 
        //(i.e. Feb. 2 = 33, not considering leap years in this problem). 

        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        {
            if (i = a) //going through all 365 days until the number of days matches
            {
                bdays[i]++; //add one to the array at position i

                if (bdays[i] > maxValue) //finding what the maximum value in the array is
                {
                    maxBday = i; //max number of days
                    maxValue = bdays[i]; //Setting new max for next line
                }
            }
        }
     }
     cout << "The most common birthday: " << maxBday; 
}
```

I will create a function later to convert the total number of days into the year as an actual date later.

My file has a single duplicate date on 1/1 so the output should be 1 for 1 day into the year but I'm not getting any output. I've put in cout statements and every part of the function is being reached but the loop never ends. I'm really lost on where my logic errors might be.

Comment: what is bdays array variable and  "bdays[i]++; //add one to the array at position i " it can increment the value not assign 1 value in the particular array variable

Comment: Is there a way to assign a value to the array at a certain position? Is it a logically possible pathway to find the most common birthday by adding +1 to the array at a position and then find the position in the array with the highest value?

Comment: `if (i = a)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Hmm ok, that makes me think I can't do this the way I'm trying to. I'm having a hard time finding another way to code this. Any ideas? Nothing specific, just general pseudo code

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(i == a)
```

because otherwise the program is going to set i to the value of a. It might not be the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the most common birthday:

1. use a multiset.
2. store every birthday in the set.
3. find the birthday that has the max `count()`.

Something like this (not tested):

```
#include <multiset>
#include <tuple>

struct Birthday { int d; int m; int y; }

bool operator<(Birthday const & lhs, Birthday const & rhs) {
      return std::tie(lhs.d, lhs.m, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.d, rhs.m, rhs.y);
}

multiset<Birthday> birthdays;
//loop and insert birthdays with birthdays.insert(Birthday{...});

auto maxIt = std::max_element(begin(birthdays), end(birthdays),
          [](Birthday const & b,
             Birthday const & b2) { return b.count() > b2.count() });
```

Not tested, but you should get the idea.